# Showing today's current rank and yesterday's

Tags: mysql

I have a table with IDs, rank, chart_date, and pageviews.  It's based on a cron job that is run nightly and compiles the number of pageviews for that ID.

For instance:

```
ID   |   RANK   |   PAGEVIEWS   |  CHART_DATE
5          1           100         2012-10-14
9          2           75          2012-10-14
13         3           25          2012-10-14
9          1           123         2012-10-13
5          2           74          2012-10-13
19         3           13          2012-10-13
```

So I'm grabbing today's chart based on 2012-10-14 and ranking the data by 1-3.  But I also want to show the rank where the ID was on the previous date.

For instance, on 2012-10-14 ID 5 was ranked 1 but on 2012-10-13 it was ranked 2.

Can I do this with one query?  Or do I have to loop thru the results based on today and do a query for each ID?

Comment: Not clear on what you need, can you post a sample desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do this with one query?

You can, but you need a JOIN between the table with today's date and the table with yesterday's date:

```
SELECT today.*, yesterday.rank
    FROM yourtable AS today
    JOIN yourtable AS yesterday
        ON (today.id = yesterday.id
            AND today.chart_date = date(now())
            AND yesterday.chart_date = date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day))
        )
    ORDER BY today.rank DESC;
```

You can even show the difference:

```
SELECT today.*, yesterday.rank AS yest, yesterday.rank-today.rank AS incr
    FROM yourtable AS today
    LEFT JOIN yourtable AS yesterday
        ON (today.id = yesterday.id
            AND today.chart_date = date(now())
            AND yesterday.chart_date = date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day))
        )
    ORDER BY today.rank DESC;

ID   |   RANK   |   PAGEVIEWS   |  CHART_DATE  |  YEST  |  INCR
5          1           100         2012-10-14     2     |   1
9          2           75          2012-10-14     1     |  -1
13         3           25          2012-10-14     4     |   1
```

(`LEFT JOIN` ensures today's data is there even if yesterday's isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Untested but something like this should work:

```
select today.id, today.rank, yesterday.rank 
from mytable as today
left join mytable as yesterday on today.id = yesterday.id 
where today.chart_date = 2012-10-14
order by pageviews desc limit 3
```

Comment: Be careful, that will get you more than you bargained for (you are also joining today with *today*, and with *all days before yesterday*). Also, it is best if you quote dates; 2012-10-14 might get you 1988, not 'October 14th, 2012'.